# Find the occurrences of an element in array

Tags: bash

```
arr=(7793 7793123 7793 37793 3214)
```

I'd like to find the occurrence of `7793`. I tried: `grep -o '7793' <<< $arr | wc -l`
However, this also counts other elements that contain `7793` (e.g. `7793123`, `37793`)

Answer (score 1):

`printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" | grep -c '^7793$'`

**Explanation:**

`printf` prints each item of the array on a new line

`grep -c '^7793$'` uses the start and end anchors to match `7793` exactly and outputs the count

Comment: It would @shellter. Thanks for the tip, my first ever `bash` answer :)

Comment: Welcome to bash-land. your wide experience with other tools will provide a valuable set of "second eyes" to many problems that appear here. Keep posting!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep` (note the correct counting of elements containing newlines, refer to documentation for a description of options used):

```
arr=(7793 7793123 7793 37793 3214 7793$'\n'7793)
printf '%s\0' "${arr[@]}" | grep --null-data -cFxe 7793
```

Output:

```
2
```

This works because variables in `bash` cannot contain the NUL character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in this case
`grep -e ^7793$`

Answer (score 0):

To make a bash script efficient (from CPU/memory consumption point of view), whenever possible, avoid running sub-shells and programs. Hence, instead of using grep or any other program, here we have the choice of using a simple loop with variable comparison and arithmetic:

```
#!/bin/bash

key=7793
arr=(7793 7793123 7793 37793 3214)

count=0
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do if [ "$i" = "$key" ]
   then count=$((count+1))
   fi
done

echo $count
```

Comment: @rowboat : don't hesitate to edit my post to enhance it with your suggestions.